# Relation of a district in a city is ranked high on nominatim than the city itself - how can i change that?

Tags: openstreetmap

This relation (https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=198913696) is one of 8 smaller districts of the German city of Essen (https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=197694959).

Nevertheless: Nominatim gives you this small subset as the first result when searching for "Essen". This leads to some unexpected behaviour. For example when using overpass turbo to search in the area {{geocodeArea:Essen}}->.searchArea; you only get results from this small district when you would expect results from the city. How can I rephrase on Overdrive? Or can I correct Nominatims behaviour somehow?

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Essen” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Essen}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “"andachtsstätte"”
  node["amenity"="place_of_worship"](area.searchArea);
  way["amenity"="place_of_worship"](area.searchArea);
  relation["amenity"="place_of_worship"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Comment: Offtopic for StackOverflow. Ask at http://help.openstreetmap.org/ or https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/issues. Also, [searching for Essen](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Essen) yields the larger area as the first result for me.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/67410/relation-of-a-district-in-a-city-is-ranked-high-on-nominatim-than-the-city-itself-why
And I just saw that you made some edits, so this is possibly the reason why the city meanwhile has become the first result.